# Can Hudson publish artifacts during the build?

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, artifacts

**Background:** I'm evaluating Hudson to replace our TeamCity CI server for building C++ and .NET projects on Windows and Linux. One of the TeamCity features I use extensively is [Publishing Artifacts while the Build is still in progress](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-PublishingArtifactswhiletheBuildisStillinProgress).

**Question:** Is there a way in Hudson to publish artifacts on demand as soon as they have been generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built in artifact publishing in Hudson does not occur until the build is complete. If you are using some other mechanism to publish your artifacts from within your build scripts then the scripts can do that whenever you want.

Comment: and if you want Hudson to do the publishing, you can break your build into multiple stages of a [pipeline](http://www.centrumsystems.com.au/blog/?p=165). i.e. the artifact is published only at the end of a stage in your pipeline, but that automatically triggers off the next stage of your pipeline.